# google calendar api server application

Tags: java, c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need some help with Google Calendar API. I tried to find information in google docs but still can't make application working.

We have a console application that works on server and performs exchange with Google calendar. This application uses Google Calendar API to get/update events in users' calendars. However, as we're accessing private user data we need to ask user about permissions to update his calendar. The issue is that when console application tries to access private data (e.g. events) web page in browser is opened where user must press "Accept" button. I would like to avoid this situation and somehow automatically press this button (or even bypass this step at all).

Can anyone help me with this? I tried to use API access and service accounts but got Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I created a "Service account" for my application from Google developer console. After that I got email for this service account e.g. ****@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Then for all users I had to share their calendars with this service account email via calendar settings. Now I can view/update Google calendar events from console application.